# Update-Database is not seeding membership tables (EF code-first)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have enabled code-first migrations.  Here's my configuration.cs:

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<App.AppDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(AppDbContext context)
    {
        SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
        context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AppDbContext, Configuration>());

        if (!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized)
        {
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
        }

        SeedMembership(context);

    }
```

With SeedMembership as:

```
   private int SeedMembership(DbContext context)
    {

        var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
        var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;

        if (!roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
        {
            roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
        }
        if (!roles.RoleExists("User"))
        {
            roles.CreateRole("User");
        }
        if (!roles.RoleExists("Moderator"))
        {
            roles.CreateRole("Moderator");
        }

        if (membership.GetUser("admin", false) == null)
        {
            membership.CreateUserAndAccount("admin", "covert");
        }
        if (!Roles.IsUserInRole("admin", "Administrator"))
        {
            roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "admin" }, new[] { "Administrator" });
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
        return membership.GetUserId("admin");
    }
```

I only have one connection string defined in my web.config:

```
        <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=App;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
```

If I run update-database locally, I see "running seed method" in package manager console and everything gets seeded as I'd expect.

However when I update-database against my azure database (not sure if azure is even relevant here), I see "Running Seed Method" but the database never gets updated with the roles / admin user.  The other tables are created.

I've spent all evening on this and don't know where else to look.  Here's what I'm using to migrate the azure db:

> Update-Database -Verbose -StartUpProjectName "App"
>   -ConnectionString "Server=tcp:app.database.windows.net,1433;Database=App;User
>   ID=Dbadmin@app;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection
>   Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Max Pool Size=100;"
>   -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"

Why isn't this working?